# How to place two ovals in a JFrame which both take up the full screen

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I need to place two ovals in a JFrame. Every oval is in a different inner class. The thing is that with BorderLayout, when using CENTER, it allows you to span all over the frame. However I cannot add the second oval as it is overwritten on the first one.

What layout manager can I use to have these two ovals both painted on the whole screen? These are going to be animated and thus might end up going on top of each other so I need them both to be drawn on the whole screen.

----Edit----

Oval is a JPanel so I have two JPanels with 2 different ovals starting at different positions.

I tried using BoxLayout like so:

```
 mainPanel = new JPanel();
 mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

 mainPanel.add(drawPanel1);
 mainPanel.add(drawPanel2);

 frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
```

However as soon as the oval passes through the center it disappears as one panel is taking the top half of the screen while the other is taking the bottom half of the screen. Other than that it is working fine. The only thing I need is to fix the layout as for both of them to take up all the screen

I also tried the GridLayout with 1 row and 1 column but still this didn't fill up the whole frame.

Comment: is `oval` a seperate `JPanel` or `JComponent` in itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 mKorbel and HFOE answers.

Using HFOEs advice:

Herre is an example I made:

It uses a `MyOval` class (a class modeled to hold sufficient data to draw an oval in a ceartain color), it also uses a single `JPanel` called `DrawPanel` which contains an `ArrayList` for `MyOval` class and a method to add to the `ArrayList`.

The `JPanel` is added o the JFrame the frame is setvisible than 2 ovals are added to the `DrawPanel` class using `addOval(...)` which will than add a new oval and to the arraylist and call repaint which in-turn will call `paintComponent` of `JPanel`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawPanel dp = new DrawPanel(500, 400);

        frame.add(dp);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        dp.addOval(0, 0, dp.getWidth(), dp.getHeight(), Color.GREEN);
        dp.addOval(0, 0, dp.getWidth(), dp.getHeight(), Color.BLUE);
        //dp.addOval(5, 5, dp.getWidth(), dp.getHeight(),Color.RED);//uncomment here to see 2nd circle better
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<MyOval> ovals = new ArrayList<>();
    private int width, height;

    public DrawPanel(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));

        for (MyOval oval : ovals) {
            g2d.setColor(oval.getColor());
            g2d.drawOval(oval.getX(), oval.getY(), oval.getWith(), oval.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    void addOval(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color) {
        ovals.add(new MyOval(x, y, w, h, color));
        repaint();
    }
}

class MyOval {

    int x, y, with, height;
    Color color;

    public MyOval(int x, int y, int with, int height, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.with = with;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWith() {
        return with;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

NB yes we cant see both ovals but thats because they are at the same co-ordinates simply do:

```
dp.addOval(0, 0, dp.getWidth(), dp.getHeight(), Color.GREEN);
//dp.addOval(0, 0, dp.getWidth(), dp.getHeight(), Color.BLUE);
dp.addOval(5, 5, dp.getWidth(), dp.getHeight(), Color.RED);//uncomment here to see 2nd circle better
```

to see the other like so:

[image]

Comment: very neat example. The thing is that I am limited in what I can do in this particular example for some reasons that there is no need to delve into. However, for a similar example (without these limitations) this is definitely the way to go. Kudos to you sir :)

Comment: @Chris thank you. though delving into these reasons may help get a better response, unless of course its criteria you are talking about i.e an assignment.

Comment: Its criteria in fact, so that is basically the reason but still your answer will definitely help those who encounter the same problem without the need to follow this criteria so obviously I chose your answer not mine since its much more neat and flexible.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than drawing in two GUI components and adding them to the JFrame, consider drawing the ovals in the same JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method and add that JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane BorderLayout.CENTER. For a more detailed answer, please provide more information in your question.

If you want the ovals separate from each other and if they *must* be in classes that extend JComponent or one of its children, then look at mKorbel's answer (1+ to it). Or if they need to be overlaid on each other, then perhaps use a JLayeredPane, and use non-opaque JPanels.

Comment: @Chris you can to put / concentrate paint from two classes to one array, loop in this array in paintComponent, +1 for clear answer

Answer (score 3):

> What layout manager can I use to have these two ovals both painted on
>   the whole screen?

see [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Answer (score -1):

I have to answer my own question as I managed to fix it with neither GridLayout nor BoxLayout. Although there might be a way how this can be achieved with this layout I found it easier to do it with no layout at all.

The following is the code:

```
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel2);
    drawPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    drawPanel2.setBounds(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
```

This code enables both two panels to take over the whole frame size which ultimately solves this problem.

Comment: very nice hack, but unfortunately its just that. Its not recommend to use null `LayoutManager` unless completely necessary (and IMO this case isnt it)

Comment: But I need it simply for these two ovals. Do you have the code how this same effect can be achieved with GridLayout? I though that I could just use GridLayout with 1 row and 1 column (which means the whole screen) but that did not work :/

Comment: @Chris: Please don't do this as it is a hack that will significantly limit your program's flexibility and your ability to update or modify the program.